# What is the best way to open a single socket from a web application (running on Tomcat) and store the returned data in collections?

Tags: sockets, tomcat

I have a data server that will stream data to my web application running on Tomcat.  I want to open a single socket to this data server (to minimize load on that data server) stream the data to my web application running on Tomcat and store the data in collections that will be continuously updated and available to all users (from Struts2 Action classes).  What is the best way to open a single socket from a web application?  Where is the best place to store the collections of data (perhaps in a ServletContextListener)?

Comment: lookup WebSockets here is a java library https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Comment: WebSockets are from the Tomcat server to a web browser.  I want to go from the Tomcat server to a data server by utilizing a socket, not a WebSocket.

Comment: WebSockets are not limited to server <-> browser, they are a modern abstraction atop HTTP which permit a persistent connection between client (your tomcat server) and server (your data server) ... its fine for a server to act at times as a client to other servers

Comment: a Websocket could be useful if you desire a push-based delivery. If not, then a regular socket could also do the job.

Comment: When you say 'continuously updated' that can mean several things IMO. Having asynchronous updates to in-memory data will bring several issues to the table: (in)consistency when updating the data, deadlocks when contending for the volatile collections. To really give a strong opinion here means knowing a little bit more about the use case.

Comment: In the least this is an unusual approach so a lot would need to be figured out by yourself. There must be a good reason to use this approach?